# Using CUBIC how to put a script on the desktop of lubuntu

Tags: boot, command-line, lubuntu, custom-distributions

In short I am creating my own custom image of lubuntu that only has rdesktop capabilities. I have made a custom script that will connect to a Windows RDP server when double clicked. But the plan is to have the computer boot to the live image off of the USB so we would not be installing the image to the hard drive (we actually plan on removing the hard drives out of the computers).

The only part I am stuck on is I can not find the Desktop folder inside of CUBIC in in the chroot terminal.

[image: Image of CUBIC terminal]

To check I booted a live CD of lubuntu to check where its Desktop folder is which is `/home/lubuntu/Desktop`. But in CUBIC it says that the path does not exist. So, am I missing something or does that path not exist until the image actually starts up? Is there a work around to my issue?

Basically I just need my `remote_desktop.sh` script to appear on the Desktop when the computer boots from the USB key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't remember from where i got the below info.. thanks to google

> The /etc/skel directory contains files and directories used during
>   account creation on a unix or linux server by the useradd program. 
>   The files and directories in /etc/skel are copied into the new user’s
>   home directory during account creation.

and below images are self explanatory as these screenshots are actual working pics on Ubuntu 18.04 with Cubic and LUbuntu 18.04 iso

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are my hero.